# pinpointing errors in loops and conditions within eachother

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I have been working on this program for some time now. It is one of those where solving one bug leads to a new one. Here is my latest stump. I have many sentences of code like this one where only the condition varies, but the second line remains.

```
if year % 400 == 0:
    nyear = "leapyear"
```

and at the end, I have this peice of code, which ensure Feb 29 will only exist for leapyears. This is also the part of the code that contains the error.

```
elif month == 2 and nyear == "leapyear":
   if day > 29:
       date = "invalid"
```

which leads to the final piece of code, which only prints the valid dates:

```
if date != "invalid":      
    print(day, months[month], year)
    break
else:
    continue
```

I didn't post my whole code because its quite long, but I can still add it if it would make the question easier to understand. This is the error I keep getting, and I have no idea how to correct it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python33\assgn21.py", line 103, in <module>
        main()
    File "C:\Python33\assgn21.py", line 82, in main
        elif month == 2 and nyear != "leapyear":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nyear' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have this:

```
if year % 400 == 0:
    nyear = "leapyear"
...
```

Then if the condition isn't met, *you never set `nyear`*. Instead, make it a flag and set it in both cases:

```
if year % 400:
    leapyear = False
else:
    leapyear = True
```

Now you can simply have:

```
elif month == 2 and leapyear:
```

Similarly, you should just have `date_valid = False` rather than `date = "invalid"`; it will make your code clearer.